# HTTP PUT in Java Servelets

Tags: java, http

I want to do some REST style cording using java sevelets and jsp. I have implemented doPUT in the servelet but when i send a Ajax request using HTTP PUT, this gives the following error.

```
type Status report

message HTTP method PUT is not supported by this URL

description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource (HTTP method PUT is not supported by this URL).
```

Any Solutions please!!!!

Comment: You'll probably need to show a small piece of sample code that gives that error so people can at least read it and perhaps run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you're using JSDK 2.0?

http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Servlets/Fundamentals/servlets.html#JSDK1_0vsJSDK2_0